# registering a simple custom task

Tags: gruntjs

Here is a very simple Gruntfile.js that doesn't produce the output I expect:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  grunt.registerTask('foo', 'I am foo', function () {
    grunt.log.writeln('test');
  });
};
```

I run this with "grunt foo" and do not get the output "test".
Can someone tell me why?

Comment: Which version of Grunt? That works for me fine on 0.4.1

Comment: I get 'Running "foo" task' and no other output.

Comment: I am using Grunt 0.4.1.

Comment: I figured it out.  This is because I am running Grunt in Cygwin.  There is a problem with some Node output on Cygwin.  It works fine from a Command Prompt.

Comment: You should at least post your solution as the answer

Comment: The solution was to run grunt from a Command Prompt instead of a cygwin window.